# Array writing race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

Imagine I have 5 threads. They each read from a unique area from array A, do some math and save to array B. Thread 1 accesses the 1st element in A and B, thread 2 accesses the 2nd element in A and B and so on.

If I have series of threads each writing to a unique area of an array does this count as a race condition?

I am doing this in Java using MPJ.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's easier to communicate to other developers with code example I would say.

Comment: depends on what you define as race. if they're all dealing with unique areas, then they can't step on each other's toes and trash another thread's values. but it'd be a race condition as to what order the values DO get written.

Comment: What is the definition of *race condition*?  Does your scenario meet this definition?

Comment: @Weston I would have used code if I had any. I was asking this question in the preliminary stages before sitting down and coding anything because I just wanted to make sure I was doing it right before I dived in.

Comment: You don't have to write real code. Even pseudocode would do. It's less writing for you and less reading for us.

Comment: @westron Ok, I'll keep that in mind should I post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, it sounds like there's no race condition provided the arrays are not being reallocated while the threads are running. Note that concurrent reads from array A—or from any memory location that does not change—are never a problem; it's only writes (or reads from changing locations) that might be an issue and none of that seems to be happening here.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Thank you for your answer. :D